# What is the name of a thread that shows the progress?

Tags: multithreading, progress

I've written a program that consists of 3 threads: 2 threads that do something useful, and the 3rd to print the progress to the console. Does a progress-printing thread have a specific name, and if so, what name does it have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably just call it 'logging', after all, the console output could easily be redirected into a file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any convention for this.  What language are you working in?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I used C for this program.